# Issue with contains in linq to sql

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I am working on MVC4 project. I am facing very weird problem with .contain().
I am using same code in other project and its working fine.

Here is my code:

```
string[] split = new string[] { };
if (Helper.DepartmentFilter != null)
{
  split = Helper.DepartmentFilter.Split(',');
}
using (dbEntities Context = new dbEntities())
{
 var result = (from me in Context.master_employee
               join ud in Context.user_detail on me.employeeid equals ud.employeeid
               where me.status.Equals("A")
               && (split.Length == 0 || split.Contains(me.department))
               select new
               {
                  ud.email,
                  me.employeeid,
                  me.name
               }).ToList();

                return result;
}
```

and I am getting error

```
The LINQ expression node type 'ArrayLength' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.
```

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: I kindly suggest, you should alter the question's title. You use "Linq to Entities" and not "Linq to SQL". It is not the same thing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move out "split.Length".

```
string[] split = new string[] { };
                if (Helper.DepartmentFilter != null)
                {
                    split = Helper.DepartmentFilter.Split(',');
                }
                var splitLength = split.Length;
                using (dbEntities Context = new dbEntities())
                {
                    var result = (from me in Context.master_employee
                                  join ud in Context.user_detail on me.employeeid equals ud.employeeid
                                  where me.status.Equals("A")
                                  && (splitLength  == 0 || split.Contains(me.department))
                                  select new
                                  {
                                      ud.email,
                                      me.employeeid,
                                      me.name
                                  }).ToList();

                    return result;
                }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for very fast response and solving problem

Answer (score 2):

Not each "flavour" of LINQ supports each of its available expressions. "Linq to Entities" for example could not perform operations on objects not related to the query. In other words, your  Linq to Entities query should contain only **entities** and **basic types** (integers, strings etc). Linq to Entities does not support all the available LINQ operations, and this could also depend on your Linq to Entities driver.

If you want to use all of the LINQ operations, I would suggest moving into "Linq to Objects" space. There you have all of the available LINQ functionality but **you have to pay the data retrieval computational cost functionality first**. Therefore, if your query has siginificant performance cost, perhaps you would have to reform it.

Hope I helped!